# When the parent's font is set to the child control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

According to the MSDN,

> The `Font` property is an ambient property that if not set, is retrieved from the parent control.

So I create a `TextBox` inside a `Form`. Make sure to delete the `TextBox1.Font` property, and when compiled, the textbox shows the parent's font as expected. Curiously, when handling `HandleCreated` event (or when checking in the control constructor when inherited) and checking `TextBox1.Font` it is not `null`.

Moreover, I change `Form1.Font` to a bigger font (from the default *Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt* to *Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt*), go to the `TextBox1.Font` property and delete the value. When compiled, the textbox shows the bigger parent's font as expected. But on `HandleCreated` event, `TextBox1.Font == null` is `false` (you won't be able to delete the control font property, but at least it won't be bold) and more interestingly the `TextBox1.Font` is not *9.75pt* size (the parents font size) but the Windows default *8.25pt*.

What am I missing?

Just to complement with code

```
private void CtlTextBox_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Font == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("null");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.Font.Size.ToString());
    }
}
```

So maybe the parent's font is set to the child control on a later event. Which event would it be? I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So maybe the parent's font is set to the child control on a later event.

Yes, the font is changed when the child control is added to parent's [`Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) collection.

> Which event would it be?

You can handle child control's [`FontChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fontchanged.aspx) event to detect font changes specifically. You can also try [`ParentChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged.aspx) if you want to track when the parent's font is set.

**How it actually works:** [`Control.Font`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font.aspx) has a getter that requests the parent's font if the font isn't explicitly set. This is covered in the documentation:

> The Font property is an ambient property. An ambient property is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control. ...

You can also check out [the reference source for `Control.Font`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,2471):

```
public virtual Font Font {
    ...
    get {
        Font font = (Font)Properties.GetObject(PropFont);
        if (font != null) {
            //return control's font if it was explicitly set.
            return font;
        }

        Font f = GetParentFont();
        if (f != null) {
            //otherwise, try to retrieve and return parent control's font
            return f;
        }
        ....
        return DefaultFont;
    }
```

So, the font itself isn't set anywhere in the process. The return value of the property just changes automatically when the child control is assigned to the parent.

The same is true for other ambient properties: [`BackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx), [`ForeColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx), [`RightToLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx), etc. You can go through the implementation of [`Control.AssignParent`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,5445) for reference.